# Disable Network Discovery prompt in Windows 2012 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I have a deployment server (WDS + MDT) for technicians to image remote servers in the data center.  Our images have all Windows Firewall profiles disabled.  Problem is recently some technicians have been answering the network discovery prompt "Do you want to find PCs, devices, and content on this network?" with the answer "no" rather than "yes" or just ignoring the prompt.  This is re-enabling the Windows Firewall and causing unnecessary troubleshooting for us to get RDP access etc.

[image: Network Discovery Prompt]

Is there some method of preventing this prompt from occurring? A GPO etc?

Comment: You should be setting this and the firewall by GPO if you don't want the end users making changes after image deployment.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't think of that.  I know where the firewall GPO is, but what would this prompt be referred to in GP?  Going to test, but will this still be set after a sysprep of a template?  These machines do not immediately go on a domain, or even the same domain so I'll have to do it via local group policy.

Comment: 1. This process should be documented. 2. Answering `YES` to the prompt should be one of the steps in the documentation. 3. The technicians should be following this documentation. - My point being, you're trying to solve a people problem here. The technicians should be educated as to how you want them to respond to this prompt and they should be following a documented process.